# Is it possible to get the entire cells of a specific row using apache POI and populate that in a cell array just like the case in jxl library?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to get all the cells of a particular row and populate that in a cell array using apache POI just like that in jxl. Is that possible ? What are the other alternate ways of performing this using apache POI ?

Comment: use a for loop and loop over all the columns of a particular row... add the data you read to the array in the loop.

Comment: 1. Use Row iterator to iterate through each row

2. Take a row object and find its nth column where n is desired col number.

3. Store its value in the array you want